# How can I disable "Ask to join new networks" in OS X?

Tags: macos, wireless-networking

When I go to *Network* preferences and try to uncheck the box that says "Ask to join new networks", the box is grey and won't let me uncheck.

How can I disable it?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your preference pane is unlocked. You will have to click the lock, enter your administrator password, and then you'll be able to uncheck the option.

[image]